# Activate cursor in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I cannot find a way to activate a cursor inside a QTextEdit without clicking inside the actual widget.  What I want to be able to do is, type something in side the QTextEdit window, click on a QPushButton and have the cursor stay active inside the QTextEdit without having to click in the window again.

Ideas?

Comment: Nope, I have also tried activateWindow() which seams like it should work but it doesn't.  I may need to call something after activateWindow() to get the cursor active too?

Comment: myTextEdit->setFocus();

check link http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus

Comment: In case `setFocus()` doesn't work for you, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43383330/3697870

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user clicks the button, you should give the focus back to the text edit using [`setFocus()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus):

```
myTextEdit->setFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the button press handler, call your QTextEdit's `setFocus()` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way.
Select your button and change focuspolicy to NoFocus.

Then you can click on your button and it will not pull the focus from your your TextEdit window, and you can run the code that your button does and it will leave the cursor in the edit window.

Comment: By setting the focuspolicy of the button to NoFocus, you're breaking accessibility of the application as the button is no longer accessible through the TAB-key.